# How do I construct a tuple in Cython?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython, cpython

I am new to cython and I am just looking for an easy way of casting a numpy array to a tuple that can then be added to and/or looked up in a dictionary.

In CPython, I can use PyTuple_New and iterate over the values of the array (adding each one to the tuple as though I were appending them to a list).

Cython does not seem to come with the usual CPython functions. How might I turn an array:

```
array([1,2,3])
```

into a tuple:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Not sure what are you asking. Every valid Python code is valid Cython code. So `a = np.array([1, 2, 3]); t = tuple(a)` should work just fine.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez you should post you comment as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cython is a superset of Python so any valid Python code is a valid Cython code. In this case, if you have a NumPy array, just passing it to a `tuple` class constructor should work just fine (just as you would do in regular Python).

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
t = tuple(a)
```

Cython will take care of converting these constructs to appropriate C function calls.